# The Dataflow workers get stuck with custom setup.py, reading data from BQ

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've been trying to get a DataFlow runner to work all day, without success. The worker just loads the job into data flow and does nothing for 1 hour.

Everything **runs as expected locally**. The process is:

Data from BQ Source -> Some data manipulation -> Writing TF Records

I think *something goes wrong when **reading data from BQ***:

```
  Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration                       User Email                       Bytes Processed   Bytes Billed   Billing Tier   Labels  
 ---------- --------- ----------------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------- ----------------- -------------- -------------- -------- 
  extract    SUCCESS   08 Nov 11:06:10   0:00:02    27xxxxxxx7565-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Looks like nothing has been processed.

Basic Pipeline:

```
import apache_beam as beam
import datetime
import tensorflow_transform.beam.impl as beam_impl
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions

@beam.ptransform_fn
def ReadDataFromBQ(pcoll, project, dataset, table):
    bq = beam.io.BigQuerySource(dataset=dataset,
                                table=table,
                                project=project,
                                validate=True,
                                use_standard_sql=True,)

    return pcoll | "ReadFromBQ" >> beam.io.Read(bq)

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
    with beam_impl.Context(temp_dir=google_cloud_options.temp_location):

        train_data = pipeline | 'LoadTrainData' >> ReadDataFromBQ(dataset='d_name',
                                                                  project='project-name',
                                                                  table='table_name')
```

it still doesn't work.

I'm using the 2.7.0 version of SDK.

```
import apache_beam as beam
beam.__version__
'2.7.0' # local
```

My setup.py file is:

```
import setuptools
from setuptools import find_packages

REQUIRES = ['tensorflow_transform']

setuptools.setup(
    name='Beam',
    version='0.0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRES,
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

> Workflow failed. Causes: The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because
>   no worker activity has been seen in the last 1h. You can get help with
>   Cloud Dataflow at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support.

1. Job_id: 2018-11-07_12_27_39-17873629436928290134 for full pipeline.
2. Job_id: 2018-11-08_04_30_38-16805982576734763423 for reduced pipeline (Just Read BQ and Write Txt to GCS)

Prior to this, everything seemed to be working correctly:

```
 2018-11-07 (20:29:44) BigQuery export job "dataflow_job_5858975562210600855" started. You can check its status with the bq...

  2018-11-07 (20:29:44) BigQuery export job "dataflow_job_5509154328514239323" started. You can check its status with the bq...

  2018-11-07 (20:30:15) BigQuery export job finished: "dataflow_job_5858975562210600855"

  2018-11-07 (20:30:15) BigQuery export job finished: "dataflow_job_5509154328514239323"

  2018-11-07 (21:30:15) Workflow failed. Causes: The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because no worker activity has been se...
```